# Submitting a form in React via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, laravel

My program works this way:

1. You choose a video from select-option menu of videos.
2. After appropriate video is selected(onChange event), list of subtitles for it are displayed in, again select-option menu for subs.
3. After appropriate subtitle is selected(onChange event), a form with textarea, prefilled with text content from subtitle file.

This stuff works as advertised. Problem occurs when i submit(submit event) changed stuff in third form whom contains that textarea with text from subtitle. I need it to press submit button twice to submit updated content that need to be written to file.

**Notice**: It works only on second submit.
Reading file and other stuff is done in Laravel and all works ok. Only this **AJAX** part is giving me the problems.

Here is my React component with AJAX code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Modsub extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.state = {
            videos: null,
            subtitles: null,
            subText: null,
            subTextFormId: null,
        };
        this.select = this.select.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.getCkEditor = this.getCkEditor.bind(this);
        this.getSubText = this.getSubText.bind(this);
    }

    getSubText(e){

        this.setState({
            subText: e.target.value,
        });

    }

    getCkEditor(){
        console.log("got ckeditor");
        CKEDITOR.replace("ckeditor");
    }

    select(e){

        this.handleSubmit(e);

    }  

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let token = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content");
        let formId =  e.target.id==="subText" ?  e.target.id : e.target.parentElement.parentElement.id;
        let url = "";
        let formElements = {};
        let myformData = new FormData();

        if(formId==="videos"){

            url = "/modSubOfVideo";
            formElements.videoId = e.target.value;
            myformData.append('videoId', formElements.videoId);

        }

        if(formId==="subtitles"){
            url = "/openSubOfVideo";
            formElements.subId = e.target.value;

            this.setState({
                subTextFormId: formElements.subId,
            });

            myformData.append('subId', formElements.subId);

        }

        if(formId==="subText"){

            url = "/writeSubOfVideo";
            formElements.subId = e.target.elements[0].value;
            formElements.subText = e.target.elements[1].value;

            this.setState({
                subText: formElements.subText,
            });

            myformData.append('subText', formElements.subText);
            myformData.append('subId', formElements.subId);

        }

        myformData.append('_token', token);
        myformData.append('message', "bravo");

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            type: 'POST',
            data: myformData,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: (response) => { 
                console.log("success");
                console.log(response);

                if(formId==="videos"){

                    this.setState({
                        subtitles: response.subtitles,
                    });
                }

                if(formId==="subtitles"){

                    this.setState({
                        subText: response.subText,
                    });
                    //this.getCkEditor();
                }

                if(formId==="subText"){

                    this.setState({
                        subText: response.subText,
                    });

                }

            },
            error: (response) => {

                console.log("error");
                console.log(response);

            }

        });

    }   

    componentDidMount(){
        //get all videos

        let token = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content");

        $.ajax({
            url: '/addSubAjax',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {_token: token , message: "bravo"},
            dataType: 'JSON',

            success: (response) => { 

                console.log("success");
                //console.log(response);

                this.setState({
                    videos: response.videos,
                });

            },
            error: (response) => {

                console.log("error");
                //console.log(response);

            }

        });

    }

    render(){
        /*console.log("****");
        console.log(this.state);
        console.log("****");*/

        let videos = this.state.videos ? this.state.videos.map((item, index) => {

            return <option key={index} value={item.id}>{item.name.substr(0, 30)+"..."}</option>

        }) : null;

        let subs = this.state.subtitles ? this.state.subtitles.map((item, index) => {

            return <option key={index} value={item.id}>{item.name.substr(0, 30)+"..."}</option>

        }) : null;

        let subtitles = subs ? <form id="subtitles" encType="multipart/form-data">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="subtitles">Choose sub to modify:</label>
                    <select className="form-control" id="subtitlesId" name="subtitlesId" onChange={this.select} required>
                        {subs}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
        : "";

        let subTextPre = "<pre>"+this.state.subText+"</pre>";
        let subText = this.state.subText ? <form id="subText" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="subId" value={this.state.subTextFormId}/>
                    <label htmlFor="subText">Modify subtitle:</label>
                    <textarea className="form-control" id="ckeditor" rows="5" onChange={this.getSubText} name="subTextId" defaultValue={subTextPre}/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        : "";

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <form id="videos" encType="multipart/form-data">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="video">Choose video:</label>
                        <select className="form-control" id="videoId" name="videoId" onChange={this.select} required>
                            {videos}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form>

                {subtitles}

                {subText}

            </div>
        );

    }

}

if(document.getElementById('modsub')){

    ReactDOM.render(<Modsub/>, document.getElementById('modsub'));

}
```

Considering my previous questions, i'm probably don't seeing the obvious .... Despite that, if any of you kind souls would point me in the right directions, i would appreciate it. Mucho kudos in advance :D

**EDIT1:**

I kind a figured out what;s causing the problem. It was ckeditor envokement. By removing `this.getCkEditor();` from condition in `handleSubmit()` method, it all works as it should be. But how to make it to work **with** ckeditor?

Comment: Could you simplify your question and code and provide a bare minimum example or codepen?

Comment: @christianeide Bare minimum would `handleSubmit` method since i determined that a problem is in it. Question simplified: Why my form needs to be submitted, with handleSubmit onSubmit event, twice for changes to take effect?

Comment: Can you remove all unnecessary functions and methods that are not needed for this problem? This is still to much code to review and get into. Something that follows these guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @christianeide Edited. Take a gander at edit note.

Comment: Is the form definitely not submitting or are you perhaps getting an ajax error response first time?

Comment: @Bryan Not submitting **with** changed value from textarea. After clicking on submit button for the second time, it submits changes from textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an asynchronous issue. Try adding a callback to ckeditor so that you are ensuring the Axiom call is made after ckeditor is finished.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Of how to do it, not why it's happening.
So, here it is:

Just before ajax call in `handleSubmit` method, i added

```
if(CKEDITOR.instances['ckeditor']){
  formElements.subText = CKEDITOR.instances['ckeditor'].getData();
  myformData.append('subText', formElements.subText);
}
```

to manually "rip" text content from ckeditor instance and set `myformData` with it. I don't know why or how, but it works. And by reading numerous posts and answers to them on numerous forums, i concluded is that this is just some of ckeditor quirks. Especially if you use it with ajax, let alone with more frameworks, frontend and backend alike.

Thanks everyone for the guidance.